# API to publish articles on Joomla

Tags: joomla-api, restful-api

Does Joomla provide any kind of APIs to publish articles?

I have Ruby on Rails application for content authoring and need to publish articles to different site which runs on Joomla

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is none.  You can check for available extensions (I doubt there will be any worth using) or create [simple CLI application](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Platform) for that. It will be resource efficient, fast and more secure then all of public extensions.